# Is there a difference between a "binary Poisson variable" and a "Bernoulli random variable"?

Tags: poisson-distribution, terminology

I am currently reading [this paper](https://elifesciences.org/articles/37815#abstract) which includes some stochastic modeling, and the authors describe a term in their model as being a "binary Poisson variable" which takes the value 1 with (time-varying) probability P(t) and 0 otherwise.

I have only recently been building up my own knowledge of proper probability theory, but would that term not just be a Bernoulli random variable? I can't find anything with a Google search for the term "binary Poisson variable" (except the paper I'm reading), but if my understanding from [Ross's text](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwi31pqt3N3jAhXMrJ4KHWT9D10QFjABegQIAxAB&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.amazon.com%2FFirst-Course-Probability-9th%2Fdp%2F032179477X&usg=AOvVaw3vLg_dQ7N473lhrN-sSHHw) is correct, the term doesn't really make sense because a Poisson variable's defining feature is its distribution over a large domain.

Is this just a strange choice of terms, or am I missing something?

Comment: I suspect they mean to say that it follows a [Poisson Binomial Distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_binomial_distribution) where the rate is not constant but depends, in their case, on $t$.

Comment: [Several things were named after Poisson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_things_named_after_Sim%C3%A9on_Denis_Poisson)

Comment: @Henry: Obviously, as he was an intellectual giant, but the question is here which of these are relevant to the OP's question...

Comment: Haven't read the article in detail but it looks like they're just talking about a Bernoulli variable.. They only use the term "Poisson" in a few locations without saying anything that suggests it has to do with either the Poisson distribution or even a Poisson Binomial but with so little made explicit it's hard to be sure.